# connect two android phone with internet without any server

Tags: java, android, http

I want to connect two android phone mean i can send and receive data from one android phone to another android phone but only via internet

suppose my phone phone is using wifi internet connection and one phone is using 3g internet connection and i want to send data from one phone to another using http and another phone will receive it

the condition is that i do not want any third party server like that, i just want to do it with only ip address,

is it possible on android? can any body give me  an example how to manage it? or any library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the WiFi transfer app (available for free in Play Store)>

*Note: For using this app, you need to be connected in the same WiFi connection.

Comment: No but i do not want any wifi connection i want only internet mediator  because may be second android phone will be far away from first android phone